# How to solve error referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to implement something similar to a file System, using Spring. I'm using JPA for interacting with my MySQL database. I'm using Hibernate to manage relationships.

Please note that I'm very new to Spring and Hibernate. Please bear with me!

Here is my general idea.

- `BaseEntity` is a class which will be used make sure all my tables have some basic columns(`name`, `created_on`, `updated_by` etc.,)
- `FileSystemEntity` is a superclass, for which I **don't** want to create a DB Table.

  - `FileSystemEntity` extends `BaseEntity`, and should have a field, `parent`. `parent` is always a `Folder`
- `Folder` is a class which extends `FileSystemEntity`. `Folder` has some folder-specific properties.
- `File` is a class which extends `FileSystemEntity`. `File` has properties like `extension`, `open_with` etc.,
- `FileSystem` is a class which extends `BaseEntity` and as a list of `FileSystemEntity`.

  - Note that since `FileSystemEntity` is not actually persisted to DB, this list will contain either `File` or `Folder`.

```
@Entity
public class FileSystem extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fileSystem", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<FileSystemEntity> fileSystemEntities;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class FileSystemEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_system_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private FileSystem fileSystem;

    /**
     * Each FileSystemEntity CAN have a parent.
     * For entities without a parent, this is null
     */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Folder.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_folder", referencedColumnName = "name")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Folder parent;

    private boolean isDir;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Folder extends FileSystemEntity {
    private String folderSpecificProperty;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class File extends FileSystemEntity {
    private String extension;
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(name) of com.example.springdemo.entity.FileSystemEntity.parent referencing com.example.springdemo.entity.Folder not mapped to a single property
```

I have also tried replacing `parent` in `FileSystemEntity` as follows:

```
    /**
     * Each FileSystemEntity CAN have a parent.
     * For entities without a parent, this is null
     */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = FileSystemEntity.class) // targetEntity is FileSystemEntity instead of Folder
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_folder", referencedColumnName = "name")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Folder parent;
```

This does get past the error, and creates the table as I want, but there is no Foreign Key created restricting `parent` in `File` and `Folder` to refer `name` of `Folder`, which is what I want.

Am I going about this the right way? Is what I want even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out.

As I said, I'm pretty new to hibernate. Apparently, we cannot use a non primary column(without the `@Id` annonation), for `referencedColumnName`.

Replaced `parent` in `FileSystemEntity` as follows:

```
    /**
     * Each FileSystemEntity CAN have a parent.
     * For entities without a parent, this is null
     */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_folder", referencedColumnName = "id")// changed from name
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Folder parent;
```

This created the tables and mapped Foreign key references.